# How to pass dynamic values into an Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

Data-binding to a directive's attributes results in an error [demo](http://jsbin.com/AjuCIHu/2/edit):

```
<div goo-progressbar value="{{progress}}"</div> 

Error: Syntax Error: Token 'progress' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{progress}}] starting at [progress}}]. at Error (<anonymous>)
```

Is there a way to pass in live values so that I can have a dynamic directive?

Comment: You can pass such values using isolated scope syntax. Read the directive documentation.

Comment: I'm using an isolated scope, but passing in a templated variable instead of a dead value is blowing it up.

Comment: could you share your complete code or set up a fiddle please

Comment: Yes, I did in the question http://jsbin.com/AjuCIHu/2/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues:

- Don't pass `{{progress}}`, rather pass the correct variable:

  ```
  <div goo-progressbar value="progress"</div>
  ```

  The `value: "=value"` scope declaration implies that.
- Do `scope.$watch("value",...)`. The `value` is in scope, as defined with `scope: {...}`.

With these changes it will work.

Comment: That eliminates the error, but doesn't seem to bind anything [demo](http://jsbin.com/AjuCIHu/6/edit). Can you edit the demo to show your suggestion?

Comment: Please implement the 2nd point as well, i.e. `$watch("value",...)` NOT `$watch(attrs.value,...)`: http://jsbin.com/UviriPu/1/edit

Comment: Thank you very much Nikos, I had been following the examples in the directives section, where I should have checked the $watch docs.

Comment: you can always pass interpolated value to the the controller but then you should be using attrs.$observe instead of scope.$watch